# jpackage Resource Naming For Background Image

Tags: jpackage

The [jpackage user's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6) states for Mac .dmg that the name of the background image is:

"Background file, application-name-background.tiff."

I have the folllowing questions;

1. Is "application-name" what is specified after the --name option?
2. Let's assume our "application-name" is "app" [ie; ... --name app ...], then is the background image named app-background.tiff?
3. Now assume our "application-name" is "my app" [ie; ... --name "my app"], then what is the name of the background .tiff file now?
4. Similar to point 3), what is the name of background tiff when "application-name" has mixed case; eg "My Application"?